# Altium: Save all schematic sheets in once

Tags: altium

I have schematic document with 15 sheets, when I anotate all the sheet it will modify all the sheets sometimes. I want to be able to save all the sheets in once without saving all of them one by one.
How to do this ?

Comment: Did you try File -> Save All or Project >> Design Workspace >> Save All? Did you read [Altium Techdoc](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/WorkspaceManager_Cmd-SaveObject_PLWorkspaceManager~SaveAll%28%28Save+All%29%29_AD) ?

Comment: I read it but I went trough this seems like. I was used to save them all one by one clicking on each sheet. Thank you

Comment: This is a horrible question. This, to me, is basic computer use. It's well established that if you want to save anything (in any program), its located under the File, if the toolbar is available. Sorry OP, but you should have known a lot better than this.

Comment: @efox29, don't reply if it is so horrible, we don't need trolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it in an answer, there are two options to save all:

1. **File >> Save All**
2. **Project >> Design Workspace >> Save All**

After launching these commands, all open projects and documents will be saved.